# Where does RTABMAP_Cloud save the Downloaded map and graph from RVIZ?

Tags: slam, navigation, rviz, rtabmap, rtab

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I used rtabmap on my turtlebot with RVIZ. From the left panel when I Download Map or Graph it does the downloads, but I cannot figure out to which path has the map and graph been downloaded to. I have checked rtabmap.db and it shows that it was updated 3 days ago even though I did the "Download" today.
Can someone point out where the map and graph from the RTABMAP is saved to when done through RVIZ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/260138/where-does-rtabmap_cloud-save-the-downloaded-map-and-graph-from-rviz?/) by [exclaiber](https://answers.ros.org/users/11366/exclaiber/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2017-04-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) on 2017-04-24**:
Where in rViz are you selecting "Download Map or Graph"? Which launch files are you using? The `rtabmap.db` file will be from the date when you last put data into the mapping system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, as Goeff pointed out, the data are stored in `~/.ros/rtabmap.db` by default. When clicking on Download Map or Graph under [rtabmap_ros/MapCloud](http://wiki.ros.org/rtabmap_ros#Map_Cloud_Display) rviz plugin, the map is download in RVIZ to be visualized. Data is not saved somewhere. If you want to save the 3D point cloud to a file (PCD, PLY), the easiest and most flexible way is to open the database with **rtabmap** standalone application, then do File->Export 3D clouds...

```
$ rtabmap ~/.ros/rtabmap.db
```

See Export cloud section on this [page](https://github.com/introlab/rtabmap/wiki/Kinect-mapping#export) for more info.

cheers

---

Originally posted by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) with karma: 6409 on 2017-04-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0